# Does a transitive kernel action on fibers imply the domain is a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid

Let $f:A\to B$ be a monoid homomorphism. Suppose the kernel acts transitively on every fiber. Does this imply $A$ is a group?

Certainly it implies every kernel element has a right inverse, which implies the kernel is a group, but I don't see how to get to the other fibers...

Comment: Does this work for a counterexample? $A = {\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z}_{\ge 0}$, $B =  {\mathbb Z}_{\ge 0}$ (both under addition), and $f$ isprojection onto the second direct factor.

Comment: @DerekHolt great counterexample. I hope I'll think of it next time. If you post this as an answer I'll be glad to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample let $A = {\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z}_{\ge 0}$, $B= {\mathbb Z}_{\ge 0}$, both under addition, and define $f$ by $f((a,b))=b$.

Then the kernel is $\{(a,0) : a \in {\mathbb Z}\}$, which is the group ${\mathbb Z}$, and it does indeed act transitively on the fibers $f^{-1}(i) = \{(a,i) : a \in {\mathbb Z}\}$.